# How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I want to do mouseover function over a drop down menu. When we hover over the menu, it will show the new options.
I tried to click the new options using the xpath. But cannot click the menus directly.
So, as the manual way I am trying to hover over the drop down menu and then will click the new options.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[13]/ul/li[4]/a"));
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
```

Comment: Check this site for detailed answer - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-hoverable-multilevel-dropdowns/

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Its not really possible to perform a 'mouse hover' action, instead you need to chain all of the actions that you want to achieve in one go. So move to the element that reveals the others, then during the same chain, move to the now revealed element and click on it.

When using Action Chains you have to remember to 'do it like a user would'.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[13]/ul/li[4]/a"));
action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("/expression-here"))).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: For me this doesn't work. My menu only gets hovered if I perform a build().perform() after a moveToElement()

Comment: The reason that this wouldn't quite work is that all calls to `webdriver.findElement(By... something)` are executed before anything else (that's the only way their result can be passed on to `moveElement`). At that time the second element that you want to find isn't visible yet because the first one still has to be hovered over. To fix this, as you said, you can insert intermediate `.perform()`s, Then for the second `findElement`, the first hover will have been `perform`ed. The given solution might work, depending on the implementation of the page, but apparently your and my mileage varied.

Answer (score 62):

None of these answers work when trying to do the following:

1. Hover over a menu item.
2. Find the hidden element that is ONLY available after the hover.
3. Click the sub-menu item.

If you insert a 'perform' command after the moveToElement, it moves to the element, and the sub-menu item shows for a brief period, but that is not a hover. The hidden element immediately disappears before it can be found resulting in a ElementNotFoundException. I tried two things:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(hoverElement).perform();
builder.moveToElement(clickElement).click().perform();
```

This did not work for me. The following worked for me:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(hoverElement).perform();
By locator = By.id("clickElementID");
driver.click(locator);
```

Using the Actions to hover and the standard WebDriver click, I could hover and then click.

Comment: The second example worked for me as well when adding .perform()

Comment: Cant belive this is still an issue... not even this works: 
    builder.moveToElement(settings)
                .moveByOffset(0, 30)
                .moveToElement(stagingMenu)
                .pause(20000)
                .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                .click(stagingMenu)
                .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
                .perform();
i even see the hover css triggerd on the element in the timeout span. but no click gets triggerd no matter what i try

Comment: How would you handle if the clickable is not an normal element and it comes like **::before**. This before comes visible when you mouse hover

Answer (score 27):

Based on [this](http://www.learnseleniumtesting.com/mouse-hover-and-other-mouse-events-in-webdriver/) blog post I was able to trigger hovering using the following code with Selenium 2 Webdriver:

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                    "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                    "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";


((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javaScript, webElement);
```

Comment: Less obvious solution, but 100% solid for my IE11 testing. If you have problems hovering with `moveToElement`, use this one! I code in C#, so it is not only Java way to do it.

Comment: Selenium [Mouse Actions](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-perform-mouseover-action-in-selenium-webdriver) & [Waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits), 

**Javascript** [initMouseEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent) [`Example`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtxvfef.php)

Comment: What is this `arguments[0]`?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh its the passed in dom reference to the second argument passed to `executeScript()`, which is a `webElement`

Comment: I get missign ref for Javascript executor. What refercne do I need to add in C#

Answer (score 12):

This code works perfectly well:

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Put your text here"));
 builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

After the mouse over, you can then go on to perform the next action you want on the revealed information

Comment: Excellent just had to add `using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;`

Answer (score 7):

Check this example how we could implement this.

[image]

```
public class HoverableDropdownTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Actions action;

    //Edit: there may have been a typo in the '- >' expression (I don't really want to add this comment but SO insist on ">6 chars edit"...
    Consumer < By > hover = (By by) -> {
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(by))
              .perform();
    };

    @Test
    public void hoverTest() {
        driver.get("https://www.bootply.com/render/6FC76YQ4Nh");

        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown"));
        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown Link 5"));
        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4"));
        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1"));
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setupDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        action = new Actions(driver);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardownDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

For detailed answer, check here - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-hoverable-multilevel-dropdowns/

Answer (score 5):

I found this question looking for a way to do the same thing for my Javascript tests, using Protractor (a javascript frontend to Selenium.)

My solution with protractor 1.2.0 and webdriver 2.1:

```
browser.actions()
.mouseMove(
  element(by.css('.material-dialog-container'))
)
.click()
.perform();
```

This also accepts an offset (i'm using it to click above and left of an element:)

```
browser.actions()
.mouseMove(
  element(by.css('.material-dialog-container'))
  , -20, -20  // pixel offset from top left
)
.click()
.perform();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Sample program to mouse hover using Selenium java WebDriver :**

```
public class Mhover {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.get("http://www.google.com");
       WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfba"));
       Actions action = new Actions(driver);
       action.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Given program can really help to user. That program is working proper. User has already accepted that..

Comment: I don't dispute it will *work*; I'm saying that you should explain *why* it might work, why what they had was not working, and what you changed.

Comment: This code is equivalent to the OP's and doesn't answer the question. Without any contextual information , it is superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
WebElement getmenu= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-2']/span[2]")); //xpath the parent

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(getmenu).perform();

Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement clickElement= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sofa L"));//xpath the child
act.moveToElement(clickElement).click().perform();
```

If you had case the web have many category, use the first method. For menu you wanted, you just need the second method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this re-usable method,

```
public void MoveThePoiterToElement(By by){
    log.info("Moving the cursor to the element");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(by));
    action.build().perform();
    log.info("Cursor moved to the element");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that and it worked normal

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPath_selector")
action.move_to_element(element).perform()
```