# Mouse hover and subsequent click on menu item

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Using selenium web-driver API in headless mode, I am trying to perform a mouse-hover on a menu item; so that all the sub menu items show up. After that, I click one of the sub menu items. The following is the code snippet:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

//Waiting for menu item to be clickable
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(menu_item)));
WebElement firstLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(menu_item));
//Hovering over the menu item
actions.moveToElement(firstLink).build().perform();
//Waiting for the sub-menu item to be clickable - ERRORS OUT HERE
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(submenu_item)));
//Getting the second link
WebElement secondLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(submenu_item));
//Click on sub menu
actions.moveToElement(secondLink).click().build().perform();
```

However, the test times out saying that the sub menu item could not be found.

I've verified that the above works **perfectly fine with the Firefox driver**.
Also, the css selectors are proper.

Are there any known issues with PhantomJs and mouse hover actions - which might explain why the code does not run with the PhantomJs driver. If so, is there any work-around for the same.

Also, is there a better way to sequence the APIs to simulate the mouse-hover-and-then-click action?

(Note: I also tried chaining the operations as mentioned in [How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-using-selenium-webdriver), but it didn't help)

Comment: I think PhantomJS does not support this yet. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Simple answer: Javascript is not being executed!

Answer (score 0):

Try using non-native JavascriptExecutor:

```
public void mouseHoverJScript(WebElement HoverElement) {
            String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript,
                    HoverElement);
}
```