# selenium webdriver opening a screen by clicking a invisible link under main menu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

i am using selenium  web driver with python.In my test case i have a menu which opens a submenu(has mouse over so i am using action_chains to click) and when click on it moves to next screen.

in that screen i need to check save, delete, reset option function.but whenever i perform click on any of those button and it also clicks on that menu and displays the drop down menu.

this screen is not frame.so i am not able to use driver.switch_to_frame(frame_id).
why i am getting this and what is the solution for this problem.

This my code:(is not one i am using but this is same with my code)

This is my main tab  1 2 3 4 (consider this all menu has submenu)

whatever new screen opens all displayed below this tab.this visible for all screens i am using.

```
menu= menu element
submenu= sub menu element
hover = ActionChains(driver)
hover.move_to_element(menu).click()
hover.click(submenu)
hover.perform()
```

## Now a new  screen opens which have save, reset options

## now doing following:

1 st
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").send_keys(value)

2 nd
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").send_keys(value)

3rd 
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").send_keys(value)

4 th
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("field to fill").send_keys(value)

## now i am clicking save button.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("save").click()
```

## during this time creates a problem when this click occurs it is clicking the menu item again and show the drop down of menu item.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site you are scraping and the code you are using?

Comment: i added over view of my code...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is how do you move the mouse (as the user would) to trigger the submenu/drop down menu. (or at least i think that's what you mean)

**Start by finding the element, then use the mouse over function provided by selenium. Then move the mouse to the next element (e.g. Save, Delete, Etc)**

Here is an example in java, the code will be similar.
*[How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)*

I believe Frame refers to another instance of a window, such as when a popup, or another site opens from a page anchor.

Comment: First point you said is absolutely correct. all the submenu items opens difference html, in that i am clicking one(this sudmenu has mouse over, so i am using Achains_chains) and shows that html screen. and if i perform click on  the button(input type=reset,type=button)in that html it is again perform the click on that menu item and shows the submenu drop down again.