# Selenium testing of Hover property

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to test the change in background color to #F67621 on hovering.
The background color code is to be compared with predefined expected value. I am using XPath as selector.

```
String xPathStr="//input[@id='add']";
String str = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathStr)).getCssValue("background-color");
```

For above code can somebody suggest me how to check for hovering of button
CSS for the above mentioned code is as follows:

```
# add:hover , #clear:hover{
    background-color:#F67621;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but i find this :

[How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("Add"));
action.moveToElement(we).perform();
assertEquals("#F67621", we.getCssValue("background-color"));
```

Other link :

http://www.learnseleniumtesting.com/mouse-hover-and-other-mouse-events-in-webdriver/

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement mousehover=org.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a"));
Actions action = new Actions(org);
action.moveToElement(mousehover).build().perform();
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)