# Selenium Webdriver - Chrome doesnt support on the Mouse over on the menu (image icon)

Tags: webdriver

After loggin the application, menu(image icon) is displayed at the left corner end. Once if we move the cursor on the icon, drop down list will show. In Firefox, its working but in chrome itsnot working. I have used the syntax "action.moveToElement(menu,0,0).click().build().perform();" its not working. Please assist me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to click on the element too soon without waiting for it to display

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
        WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='nav']/div[@class='top-menu-for-more clearfix']/ul/li/a/span[text()='View All Courses']"));
        actions.moveToElement(subLink);     
        //Now wait for sometime before clicking it
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        actions.click().build().perform();
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: I tried with above syntax, still i'm facing same issue. But its working in firefox.

Comment: Okay. I have a hunch here. Can you try to not click the element and see what happens. i.e. only execute the following: Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);

Comment: My requirement is when mouser over the Menu image then system display dropdown list of A,B,C,D then mouse over B element then child element like B1,B2 etc displayed. Currently webdriver is recognised the menu image but dropdown list is not coming. Pls help me Fahim.

Comment: WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='vMenu']/a"));
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(menu).perform();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Engineering"));
  Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
  action1.moveToElement(submenu).perform();
  System.out.println("Eng select");
  Thread.sleep(1000);
         WebElement Chcktype = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Maintenance Facility"));
  Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
  action2.moveToElement(Chcktype).click().perform();

Comment: Okay in Chrome, it is not directly possible to do a mouse over action, one at a time. You have to chain the actions all together to perform a task. In your case, the code should look like this:
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='vMenu']/a")); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Engineering")))).moveTOElement(By.linkText("Maintenance Facility").click().build().perform();

Comment: Site implementation differences sometimes make it difficult to pin-point the actual problem :( . My last bet would be 
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='vMenu']/a")); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.moveToElement(menu).perform().moveToElement(submenu).perform(); //--> Here going to the inner child
WebElement Chcktype = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Maintenance Facility")); //-->Locating the inner child to click on
//Wait if needed here
Chcktype.click(); --> click inner most child

Comment: Else please take a look at this page for more answers 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Thanks Fahim. I tried your syntax also not worked. Thanks a lot for continous response.