# Is there a difference between the C# test suite for Webdriver and Selenium RC

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am new to automation test and have been assigned a task to create a automation test for a web app using selenium. I have been reading into WebDriver and Selenium RC and weighing on which one to go with. They both have a downfall which is preventing me from steping forward
- Selenium RC has all the selenium commands however it selenium IDE doesn't export test suites in C# for RC
- Selenium IDE exports test suites in C# for WebDriver however it doesn't have all the selenium commands integrated in it

So Im currently leaning towards RC and i would just write the test suite myself. However,I am not familiar with test suites and was wondering if the test suites for RC is the same/similar as WebDriver C# TestSuite exported by Selenium IDE.

Comment: Easy decision: Selenium RC has been deprecated several **years** ago. Any new project should start with Selenium WebDriver!

Comment: I just saw that on the selenium homepage. thanks @SiKing. The problem im having with WebDriver is that it doesn't have the mouseOver command. Do you know anyway I could solve this?

Comment: When I export the test case, the mouseOver command gives me this "// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [mouseOver | link=Navigate | ]]"

Comment: Try to get off Selenium IDE - it is intended only for demonstration purposes, and is **not** a real IDE! http://stackoverflow.com/q/17293914/3124333

Comment: that is great!Thank you so much for the link.Appreciate it

Comment: In C# WebDriver the equivalent of IDE's mouseOver would be the MoveToElement Action.

IWebElement link = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Navigate"));
var action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(link).Perform();