# Click on CSS menu with when running the Framework using ANT

Tags: css, selenium, menu

I'm trying to click on a `CSS menu`, first I need to hover over and then click a sub menu link
I am able to do this when i run my test as an individual or a `JUnit` test, but when I run the same test from ant(I have created a batch file used to run the tests) hover does not work.

code for hovering and click on a sub menu link

```
String menuhoverlink = "//*[@id='orders']/a";    
String sublink = "//*[@id='orders']/ul/li[4]/a";    
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id(menuhoverlink))).build().perform();    
driver.findElement(By.id(menuhoverlink))
```

1. I need to understand why hovering and clicking on a sub menu link does not work when I run the test using ant?
2. How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `menuhoverlink` and `sublink` are not `ids` and you are using `By.id()`to locate them which is wrong.

```
Use `By.xpath()`
```

Second, you never performed any `click()`on the element. Something following should work.

```
String menuhoverlink = "//*[@id='orders']/a";    
String sublink = "//*[@id='orders']/ul/li[4]/a";    
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(menuhoverlink))).build().perform();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath(sublink)).click();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) for similar options including `javascript`

Comment: Hi Saifur, Thanks for your comments, i am able to hover and click on elements when i run the Junit test directly from eclipse. The problem is when i run the same test using ant hover does not work. I need to know what is the difference when we directly run Junits. tests from eclipse and running Junit tests from ant. Should i include any task or target in my build.xml to make sure hover will work i run the Junit tests through ant?

Comment: @user3911901 I am afraid the original code is wrong. I am not sure how that works.