# Selenium webdriver Action not working with primefaces tieredmenu

Tags: java, selenium, primefaces, selenium-webdriver

this is a well-known difficulty. I found several references ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java), [here](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/mouse-hover-action/) and [here](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-perform-mouseover-action-in-selenium-webdriver)), but none seems to work with the scenario with which I am working.

I have a menu made with Primefaces (tieredMenu). It renders a html as follows. I need to click on the second submenu item of the first menu item (`<a class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all configmenuPartner" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'frm:configmenuPartner',formId:'frm'});return false;" href="#" tabindex="-1">`).

I'm using the following code (webdriver 2.44.0 - ie driver) to perform the action:

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement mainMenu = webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.configmenu"));
action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".configmenuPartner"))).click().build().perform();
```

The first **moveToElement** seems to be working, since the correct submenu is rendered and shown, but instead of clicking into the second submenu, selenium "clicks" in the second item of the main menu (`<li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent" aria-haspopup="true" role="menuitem">`).

I tried to use xpath, using By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'configmenuPartner')]") but the result was the same.

Please, could you help me pointing out a path or showing me some mistake?

TIA,

Bob

```
<div id="frm:mnuNsmg" class="ui-menu ui-tieredmenu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" role="menubar" style="width: 13.5em;">
   <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" tabindex="0"></div>
      <ul class="ui-menu-list ui-helper-reset">
         <li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent configmenu ui-menuitem-active" aria-haspopup="true" role="menuitem">
            <a class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
            <ul class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-list ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-menu-child ui-shadow" role="menu" style="left: 162px; top: 0px; z-index: 1031; display: block;">
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
                   <a class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all configmenuPartner" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'frm:configmenuPartner',formId:'frm'});return false;" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
                <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
                ::after
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent" aria-haspopup="true" role="menuitem"></li>
        <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
        <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"></li>
    </ul>
    ::after
</div></div>
```

Comment: instead of `webdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".configmenuPartner"))` can you try with `mainMenu.findElement(By.cssSelector(".configmenuPartner"))`...

Comment: Thanks @VivekSingh. I tried, but the behaviour was the same.