# In Selenium how to select an option if the span class and div class are not unique

Tags: select, selenium, unique, element

We have tabs called Community, Resources and Support which have the same section class Div Class and Span Class attributes as seen in the html code below.
How to "select" or choose one of the tabs and then traverse down the path to the links.

```
<section class="s-fn-item">
<div class="s-fn-wrapper-item">
    <h5 class="s-fn-title-item">
        <span class="s-fn-item-link">Community</span>
    </h5>
<div class="s-fn-wrapper-sub-menu bg-base bg-shadow-down-medium fn-    offscreen" style="display: block; height: 245px;">
        <ul class="s-fn-sub-menu-item">
<li class="s-fn-promo-sub-menu-item"><a href="Here is the link" class="s-fn-sub-item-link" title="QA Community Home">QA Community Home</a>
        </li>
<li class="s-fn-promo-sub-menu-item"><a href="/community" class="s-fn-sub-item-link" title="Community Home">Community Home</a>
        </li>
<li class="s-fn-promo-sub-menu-item"><a href="/community/events-webinars" class="s-fn-sub-item-link" title="Community Events">Community Events</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="s-fn-item">
    <div class="s-fn-wrapper-item">
        <h5 class="s-fn-title-item">
        <span class="s-fn-item-link">Resources</span>
       </h5>
   <div class="s-fn-wrapper-sub-menu bg-base bg-shadow-down-medium fn-offscreen"     style="display: block; height: 227px;">
    <ul class="s-fn-sub-menu-item">
<li class="s-fn-promo-sub-menu-item"><a href="/support/articles-and-how-tos" class="s-fn-sub-item-link" title="Articles and How-Tos">Articles and How-Tos</a>
        </li>
<li class="s-fn-promo-sub-menu-item"><a href=”Here is the link” class="s-fn-sub-item-link" title="Blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
```

Storymakers
        
    
    
    
    
    
       
        
            Support
        
    
       
    Support Home
        
Contact Us
        
    Installation and Licensing

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **@user1433852** for using relative xpaths as they make life easier.. :) . I have formulated relative xpaths below to find the menu **Community/Resources** and then the xpath for a sub-menu item under them:

1. **`//span[.='Community']`**
   This will select the **'span'** element with the exact inner HTML or text as **'Community'**.
   **`//span[.='Community']/ancestor::div[@class='s-fn-wrapper-item']//a[@title='QA Community Home']`** 
   This will select the **'a'** element with title **'QA Community Home'** under the div element with class **'s-fn-wrapper-item'** which is the [ancestor of the](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlancestor.php) **'span'** element with the exact inner HTML or text as **'Community'**.
2. Similarly, 
   **`//span[.='Resources']`**
   This will select the **'span'** element with the exact inner HTML or text as **'Resources'**.

   **`//span[.='Resources']/ancestor::div[@class='s-fn-wrapper-item']//a[@title='Articles and How-Tos']`**
   This will select the **'a'** element with title **'Articles and How-Tos'** under the div element with class **'s-fn-wrapper-item'** which is the ancestor of the **'span'** element with the exact inner HTML or text as **'Resources'**.

So, in both the cases above I am using the the primary items, i.e., **Community and Resources** to get to their submenu items, that are, **QA Community Home and 
Articles and How-Tos**, respectively.

Comment: I am getting element not visible exception...    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException was unhandled
  Message=element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.135)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1119

Comment: @SameerShah: Which element is throwing that? **Community** or **QA Community Home** ? Also, please do let me know, if the element **QA Communtiy Home** is a submenu item which appears only after hovering or clicking on **Community** ..

Comment: HI Subh, Yes you are correct. QA Community Home is a submenu  item appears only after hovering on Community. The error is from QA Community Home.

Comment: In case you are using Java as the language to automate, you can use [Action class to hover over **Community**  and then click on **QA Community Home**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17294390/4193730).. Or you can use something similar if you are using some other language. Hope this helps..