# Mouse hover in selenium using Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Need perform hover on Electronics highlighted on below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qChww.jpg)

```
    cd.get("http://flipkart.com/");
    cd.manage().window().maximize();
    Actions mobile = new Actions(cd);
    WebElement electronics= cd.findElement(
    By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span"));
    //electronics.click();
    mobile.moveToElement(electronics);
    mobile.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) contains the same question as yours, please consider viewing the first answer, it was accepted. 
PS : please let me know if it worked, else we can search another solutions! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks..I will try and let u know

Comment: I tried answer from above mentioned post.. But it's not performing action neither giving an error @Mohamed EL AYADI