# Unable to find required element using nested findElement method

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to automate some test scenarios of our e-commerce site.
There is a page where some products are listed. I want to randomly select one product, and click '*Add to Cart*'. The only problem is, the button would be displayed only when we hover over the product and all the add to cart buttons have same properties.
So, I've used nested `findElement` method to drill it down to the particular button.

```
prods = getObjects("productlisting_prodinfo");
WebElement outer = prods.get(itemposition);
builder.moveToElement(outer).build().perform();
WebElement ele1=outer.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("prodinfo_addtocart")));
ele1.click();
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work as intended, and always selects the button on the first product. The hovering is done successfully, but button click is not as intended.

Any help to get this done would be highly appreciated.

[image: Page]

Comment: You need to use `ActionChains` to hover over your element at first and then to click on it. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: The hovering is being done properly. The problem lies in finding the button. For testing, I just captured a List of all the elements using nested findElements method, and seems like instead of one, it captures all the buttons. I'm rechecking to see if the xpath locator needs to be amended.

Comment: Whatever is your xpath, guessing coming from some property file append an '.' to it. When you use a xpath to search using an element as you have instead of the driver you need a dot at the beginning to restrict the search to the descendants of that element. Otherwise it searches the whole document.