# Css Selector for the Log Out button

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have a LogOut button in a page. I am trying to automate it in Selenium.Following is the source code for that element.

```
<a class="_2k0gmP" data-reactid="53" href="#">Log Out</a>
```

This is the code that i am using

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._2k0gmP[text='Log Out']"));
```

But i am repeatedly getting No Such Elemet found exception and sometimes Invalid Selector Exception. Could somebody please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `InvalidSelectorException` because you can't use `cssSelector` to find element based on it's inner HTML text. For that you could use xpath or linkText selectors.

xpath:  `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Log Out']");`

linkText: `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out"));`

`NoSuchElement` exception was probably thrown because you left out `_` in class selector as @gecki said so your selector was searching for class which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes @acikojevic , the linkText option actually worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not leave out the underscore:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._2k0gmP[text='Log Out']"));
```

However, in this case I would prefer

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out"));
```

Comment: You can't locate text contained using a CSS selector.

Comment: @Gecki , the linkText selector actually worked.Thanks !!.

Answer (score 0):

xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Log Out']");
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be better if you offered an explanation of the answer rather than just a code only answer.