# selenium - Not able to locate login

Tags: selenium

I am trying to locate the login into a webpage but am not able to do the same as the element is not visible - getting Nosuchelement exception.

i tried using the below code but each time i get the exception.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("admin");

Can anyone please help me in this.

Thanks HTML Code for the page is :-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Retail-J</title>
    </head>


    <frameset name ="mainFrameset" id ="mainFrameset" rows="55,*" frameborder="1" framespacing="2" border="2" bordercolor="#000000">
        <frame name="titleFrame" src="title.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
        <frameset name="innerFrameset" id="innerFrameset" cols="20.0%,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0" >
            <frame name="contentFrame"  src="dynamicContents.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="noresize" target="mainFrame" scrolling="auto">
            <frame name="mainFrame" src="Welcome.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto">
        </frameset>
        <noframes> 
            <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
            Sorry your browser does not support framesets. 
             </body>
        </noframes> 
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Please find the html code below : -

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague as you don't provide any example of the related DOM; however you can start by verifying that the intended element is actually visible for the browser. Some times login elements are hidden and only appear upon a user action (such as mouse click or mouse over). 
Selenium has a couple of functions that will allow you to render the element visible (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)). If nothing else seems to work, you can use the [Javascript executor](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/javascript-and-selenium-javascriptexecutor/) to find the element and return it for use, although it is not considered a good practice.

Comment: The Page source displays as

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchElement exception means that your locator is not correct. Try below things:

1. Try To Find element using ID , NAME or XPATH. Make sure locator is unique?
2. Check if element is inside a iframe/frame?
3. Wait for element visibility.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: So your element is inside frame. Please first switch inside frame (frame name="contentFrame")  , and then interact with input field.

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified what language you're using for your project so I'm just going to give an answer in C#.

At a guess I would assume it's a mixture of the web driver executing too fast and also using the wrong locators, possibly a login page that uses the same ID multiple times too which complicate things.

Add the following wait to your solution and see if it helps:

```
    Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
```