# How to select this textarea?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I need to put the cursor in the textarea element using Selenium. The element has no ID. 
I have tried:

```
eventDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[class*=\"CodeMirror\"")).click();
```

and it throws NoSuchElementException

[image]

[image: Web Page and underlying code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textarea` has no `@class` - it's an attribute of ancestor `div`. Try below code instead:

```
eventDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.CodeMirror textarea")).click();
```

or with ExplicitWait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(eventDriver,10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.CodeMirror textarea"))).click();
```

*Update*

```
WebElement element = eventDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.CodeMirror textarea"))
JavascriptExecutor jse = ((JavascriptExecutor)eventDriver);
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Comment: It throws a different exception: ElementNotInteractable. The detail in the exception says "Element <textarea> could not be scrolled into view."

Comment: Do you need to click it or to enter some string?

Comment: Yes, I need to do both

Comment: New exception: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: div.CodeMirror textarea (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Do you need to hover textarea to make it interactive?

Comment: I don't know. Can I programmatically hover just in case?

Comment: Yes, you can try [ActionChains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java). Also try updated answer once again

Comment: Welcome. You can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem. Thanks