# Mouse over not pointing and hovering on the specified object - Mouse pointer is not moving into the object

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to seek for your help. Seems I need another eyes to look into my script as it is not working. I do not know what is wrong with the code. Did I missed something?

Below is my script:

```
DriverUtils.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Actions action= new Actions(DriverUtils.getDriver());              
WebElement fundAllocation = DriverUtils.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("(*//div[@data-index = '" + dataIndex + "']/descendant::div//*[contains(@class, 'mli-donut-chart')]//*[contains(@transform,'translate')]//*[contains(@style,'fill-opacity: 1')])["+ x +"]"));
action.moveToElement(fundAllocation).build().perform();
```

I also try this one on perform, but still didn't work.

> action.moveToElement(fundAllocation).click().build().perform();

Comment: What is the driver you use?

Comment: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java">this</a> may help you

Comment: Still not work in my case. Thanks for the reference anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You at least first need to define import `Actions` and define `action`:

in your imports add

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Then before you perform the action with something like

```
Actions action = new Actions(DriverUtils.getDriver());
action.moveToElement(fundAllocation).click().build().perform();
```

Does that help?

Comment: This is currently my code/script - However, I do not see the mouse pointer moving into the object... and it is not hovering the object..

Comment: What if you add a `.click()` before `.build()` -- edited into my answer.

Comment: Yes,I already did that, still not work. Is there any othre way to do a mouse over? Thanks

Comment: Ugh I hate `Actions`, they never work.  Sorry, not sure how to fix this.