# Examples of action chains with selenium python, human like mouse movements then click the button examples;

Tags: python, selenium

I need human like mouse movements prior to the mouse clicking the follow button. As this website seems to be checking your a human before clicking. Is this possible using action chains, looked at loads of examples but nothing seems to fit.

```
eg.,

def __init__(self): 
self.action = ActionChains(self.driver)
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

eg.,

def follow(self):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//header//button[text()=\"Follow\"]").click()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel not if op needs to create "human-like mouse movements" before clicking the button

Comment: @Drav please clarify.

Comment: I move the mouse pointer to the button and press click, from some random point on the screen and not in a straight line.

Comment: @Drav you do this yourself and the human-like part is irrelevant now? Then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/

Comment: So the code above finds the follow button and clicks without any movements and this action is blocked, if you do the action yourself with the mouse and left click its not blocked.

Comment: Then you could use the method `moveByOffset(x,y)`

Comment: What is "blocking" the action? Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you add, in order, the sequence of events that does work?