# how to scrape links from hidden span class HTML?

Tags: python, html, selenium, hover

I'm learning web scraping as I scrape real world data from real websites.
Yet, I've never ran into this type of issues until now.
One can usually search for wanted HTML source codes by right-clicking the part of the websites and then clicking inspect option. I'll jump to the example right away to explain the issue.

[image]

From the above picture, the red color marked span class is not there originally but when I put(did not even click) my cursor on a user's name, a small box for that user pops up and also that span class shows up. What I ultimately want to scrape is the link address for a user's profile which is embedded inside of that span class.I'm not sure but IF I can parse that span class, I guess I can try to scrape the link address but I keep failing to parse that hidden span class.

I didn't expect that much but my codes of course gave me the empty list because that span class didn't show up when my cursor was not on the user's name. But I show my code to show what I've done.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

#Incognito Mode
option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

#Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe",options=option)

driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html")
time.sleep(3)

#parse html
html =driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

hidden=soup.find_all("span", class_="ui_overlay ui_popover arrow_left")
print (hidden)
```

Are there any simple and intuitive ways to parse that hidden span class using selenium? If I can parse it, I may use 'find' function to parse the link address for a user and then loop over all the users to get all the link addresses. 
Thank you.

=======================updated the question by adding below===================

To add some more detailed explanations on what I want to retrieve, I want to get the link that is pointed with a red arrow from the below picture. Thank you for pointing out that I need more explanations.

[image]

==========================updated code so far=====================

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#Incognito Mode
option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

#Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe",options=option)

driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html")
time.sleep(3)

profile=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mainContent']")
profile_pic=profile.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui_avatar large']")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(profile_pic).perform()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(profile_pic).click().perform()

#So far I could successfully hover over the first user. A few issues occur after this line.
#The error message says "type object 'By' has no attribute 'xpath'". I thought this would work since I searched on the internet how to enable this function.
waiting=wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.xpath,('//span//a[contains(@href,"/Profile/")]'))))

#This gives me also a error message saying that "unable to locate the element".
#Some of the ways to code in Python and Java were different so I searched how to get the value of the xpath which contains "/Profile/" but gives me an error.
profile_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span//a[contains(@href,"/Profile/")]').get_attribute("href")
print (profile_box)
```

Also, is there any way to iterate through xpath in this case?

Comment: So you want to know how to simulate the "hover" user action in selenium, so that the popover element will be present in the DOM. Please make your question more clear and perhaps more specific.

Comment: Which data you want to retrieve in popup box?

Comment: @Yun Hi, Yun. I've just updated the question on what I want to retrieve.

Comment: @Adriano I didn't know that there was a hover function until you just mentioned it. Thank you for bringing it up. Yes. I think that would work since the popover element will show up as I put my cursor on a user's profile.

Comment: Will this help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25003010/4603295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Python

The below code will extract the href value.Try and let me know how it goes.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html");

#finds all the comments or profile pics
profile_pic= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='prw_rup prw_reviews_member_info_hsx']//div[@class='ui_avatar large']")

for i in profile_pic:
        #clicks all the profile pic one by one
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).perform()
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).click().perform()
        #print the href or link value
        profile_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span//a[contains(@href,"/Profile/")]').get_attribute("href")
        print (profile_box)

driver.quit()
```

### Java example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./lib/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html");

        //finds all the comments or profiles
        List<WebElement> profile= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='prw_rup prw_reviews_member_info_hsx']//div[@class='ui_avatar large']"));

        for(int i=0;i<profile.size();i++)
        {
            //Hover on user profile photo
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.moveToElement(profile.get(i)).perform();
            builder.moveToElement(profile.get(i)).click().perform();
            //Wait for user details pop-up
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span//a[contains(@href,'/Profile/')]")));
            //Extract the href value
            String hrefvalue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span//a[contains(@href,'/Profile/')]")).getAttribute("href");
            //Print the extracted value
            System.out.println(hrefvalue);
        }
        //close the browser
        driver.quit(); 

    }

}
```

output

> ```
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/861kellyd
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/JLERPercy
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/rayn817
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/grossla
> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Profile/kapmem
> ```

Comment: @Todd Is this working? if so can i get upvote for this answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use requests library instead of selenium.

When you hover on username, you will get Request URL as below.

[image: First,]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g60742-d7951369-or20-Groove_Stone_Getaway-Asheville_North_Carolina.html')
print(html.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

# Find all UID of username
# Split the string "UID_D37FB22A0982ED20FA4D7345A60B8826-SRC_511863293" into UID, SRC
# And recombine to Request URL
name = soup.find_all('div', class_="memberOverlayLink")
for i in name:
    print(i.get('id'))

# Use url to get profile link
response = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/MemberOverlay?Mode=owa&uid=805E0639C29797AEDE019E6F7DA9FF4E&c=&src=507403702&fus=false&partner=false&LsoId=&metaReferer=')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find('a')
print(result.get('href'))
```

This is output:

```
200
UID_D37FB22A0982ED20FA4D7345A60B8826-SRC_511863293
UID_D37FB22A0982ED20FA4D7345A60B8826-SRC_511863293
UID_D37FB22A0982ED20FA4D7345A60B8826-SRC_511863293
UID_805E0639C29797AEDE019E6F7DA9FF4E-SRC_507403702
UID_805E0639C29797AEDE019E6F7DA9FF4E-SRC_507403702
UID_805E0639C29797AEDE019E6F7DA9FF4E-SRC_507403702
UID_6A86C50AB327BA06D3B8B6F674200EDD-SRC_506453752
UID_6A86C50AB327BA06D3B8B6F674200EDD-SRC_506453752
UID_6A86C50AB327BA06D3B8B6F674200EDD-SRC_506453752
UID_97307AA9DD045AE5484EEEECCF0CA767-SRC_500684401
UID_97307AA9DD045AE5484EEEECCF0CA767-SRC_500684401
UID_97307AA9DD045AE5484EEEECCF0CA767-SRC_500684401
UID_E629D379A14B8F90E01214A5FA52C73B-SRC_496284746
UID_E629D379A14B8F90E01214A5FA52C73B-SRC_496284746
UID_E629D379A14B8F90E01214A5FA52C73B-SRC_496284746
/Profile/JLERPercy
```

---

If you want to use selenium to get popup box,

You can use ActionChains to do hover() function.

But I think it's less efficient than using requests.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: Thank you @Yun Your solution is really intuitive. But your output gives only a one link. A following question is that how do I hover all the users? I tried all day to make it but couldn't find. It is true that URL from network shows up as I hover each of the users manually. I searched for how to hover over multiple elements in a row but there weren't any clear materials for that. If I can successfully hover all the users, then your code would work the best.