# Get tooltip text

Tags: java, selenium, dom

How can I get the tooltip text using Selenium Java if the tooltip element doesn't exist in the DOM?

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Isn't this basically the question of how to hover with Selenium, asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: I have already got it. Thanks.