# Access element inside shadow root in selenium with Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, shadow-dom, queryselector

I am trying to access the "Solve the challenge" button inside the `shadow-root (closed)` element as shown below:

[image: DOM of button]

I have tried:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"solver-button\"]")).click();
```

but it can't access the button because of the `shadow-root` element.

I am looking for a method to access the button with id `solver-button` inside the shadow root element.

Answer (score 0):

```py
shadowbutton = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div[class=\"button-holder help-button-holder\"]').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[id=\"solver-button\"]')")
shadowbutton.click()
```

`shadowRoot` is not part of the DOM so you first have to find the root element that has the shadow root and then call it using `shadowRoot` and then call the target element from it.

Comment: I got this error:
javascript error: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null

Comment: arre you able to find element with that class using find elemnt ?

Comment: is there any iframe or other shadow roots in this tree as perent of element with calss  class="button-holder help-button-holder"

Answer (score 0):

The element with *title* as **Solve the challenge** is within a **`#shadow-root (open)`**

[image: shadow_Root]

---

### Solution

To `click()` on the desired element you can use `shadowRoot.querySelector()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebElement solverButton = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('div.button-holder.help-button-holder').shadowRoot.querySelector('button#solver-button')");
solverButton.click();
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)
- [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793)

Answer (score 0):

In case that it suffices to click on the parent element (`<div class="button-holder help-button-holder"></div>`) of the `shadow-root` element, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17293914) may be helpful.

To perform a mouse click on the `help-button-holder` element, you can use the [`moveToElement` method](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)) as follows:

```java
WebElement buttonHolderElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rc-imageselect\"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]"));
Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);
actionProvider.moveToElement(buttonHolderElement).click().build().perform();
```

Check the [selenium documentation on mouse actions in detail](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/mouse_and_keyboard_actions_in_detail/) for reference.