# Selenium VBA - How to move mouse to position (x,y)?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to move the mouse in a certain position (0,0). After a previous click action I need in fact to move away the mouse from that position, as it's interfering with the next action I need to do.

I've found following Java code which is a perfect starting point but I'm not able to translate it into VBA and to adapt to my need.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[13]/ul/li[4]/a"));
action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("/expression-here"))).click().build().perform();
```

Sources:

[How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

https://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html

Comment: Do you want to move to an element or a co-ordinate?

Comment: @QHarr, I could find a (Java) example which move to an element, but my need is to move to a coordinate

Comment: Co-ordinates will vary according to screen resolution unless you want a scrollTo on a weboage. Are you sure it is not sufficient to move to a different element then carry on with program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
Set el = driver.FindElementByXPath("//head")
driver.Actions.MoveToElement(el).Perform
```

As per @QHarr comment I didn't move to a coordinate but to an element: "head".
This way my next selenium step is not disturbed by mouse position, which previously triggered a "mousehover" event.